# Blogger Template HTML editor changes broke my blog

Tags: jquery, html, templates, blogger

I am trying to add jQuery tooltips to my Google Blogger Template. But I found out, that when I add some code to template HTML, the result is that no content on the page is visible.

This is how my my blog looks like when I apply new template:
[image: This is how my my blog looks like when I apply new template:]

and this is what it looks like, when I change something in the Template HTML editor and get it right back and save -> so no real change.
[image]

The only thing I can do is to Apply new template and let it be.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code you're adding, or the template HTML.

Comment: Same here. I use Simple template. HTML editor broke site with any changes.

Answer (score 0):

First change your blogger template to custom blogger template and then try this method. If it don't works than try another method to add "jQuery tooltips".